# devicestatechecker cancelled is coming frequently in android monitor

Tags: android

I have tried all possible options.   When i am trying to run the app the app is woking fine with all functionality .However the below messages are coming in android monitor which is very annoying.Please help me in finding the reason why it is coming.

```
08-04 00:19:53.038 2322-2322/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
08-04 00:19:53.039 2322-2322/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
08-04 00:19:53.058 2322-7024/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
08-04 00:19:53.059 2322-2473/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@136a5d5
08-04 00:19:53.061 1308-1333/? W/APM_AudioPolicyManager: getInputForAttr() failed opening input: samplingRate 16000, format 1, channelMask 10
08-04 00:19:53.062 2322-2473/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 993, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
08-04 00:19:53.064 2322-2473/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
08-04 00:19:53.064 2322-2473/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
08-04 00:19:53.064 2322-2473/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@136a5d5
08-04 00:19:53.067 2322-2473/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
08-04 00:19:53.069 2322-2322/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
08-04 00:19:53.099 2322-2473/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@136a5d5
08-04 00:19:53.099 2322-7024/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
08-04 00:19:53.099 2322-7024/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
08-04 00:19:53.100 2322-6584/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
08-04 00:19:53.101 2322-7024/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
            com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
            Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
            at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
08-04 00:19:53.101 2322-7024/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
08-04 00:19:53.106 2322-2322/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
08-04 00:19:53.106 2322-2322/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
08-04 00:19:53.106 2322-7023/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
```

Comment: This messages are coming continiously,look like its in a infinite loop.

Comment: I tried creating a new project.After that the hellow world program,the default one ran fine.Again when i restarted the android studio and tried running the same default hello world i found following error.

Comment: On android monitor the message coming :

08-07 00:36:45.760 2745-4892/com.google.android.gms W/PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.